# How can I bind static string?

Tags: binding, static, swiftui

For example, I have this interface:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @Binding var statictext : String

    var body: some View {
        Text("My New Text: \(statictext)")
    }
}
```

and this class:

```
class Strings
{
    public static var mytext = "MyText"
}
```

How can I initialize ContentView? I need, than text in interface become "My New Text: new text" when I change the value of Strings.mytext = "new text"

P.S.: sorry for my English)))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if this is the right answer for this question but you could do this, even thou it feels kinda dirty to me.

```
import SwiftUI

class Strings
{
    public static var mytext = "MyText"
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var statictext : String {
        willSet {
            Strings.mytext = newValue
        }
    }

    init() {
        self._statictext = State(initialValue: Strings.mytext)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("My New Text: \(statictext)")

            Button(action: {
                self.statictext = "Test"
            }) {
                Text("Button")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I update screen, when static text is changed?